# AlertDialog with GIF

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using a AlertDialog to show a message to the user with buttons, is possible to add a gif image to AlertDialog?

Here is a examaple more or less what I want to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxLBu.jpg

Code:

```
public static void StartPowerSaverIntent(Context context)
        {
            ISharedPreferences settings = context.GetSharedPreferences("ProtectedApps", FileCreationMode.Private);
            bool skipMessage = settings.GetBoolean("skipAppListMessage", false);
            if (!skipMessage)
            {
                ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = settings.Edit();
                foreach (Intent intent in POWERMANAGER_INTENTS)
                {
                  if (context.PackageManager.ResolveActivity(intent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly) != null)
                    {
                        var dontShowAgain = new Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatCheckBox(context);
                        var imagetest = new Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatImageView(context);


                        dontShowAgain.Text = "Do not show again";

                        dontShowAgain.CheckedChange += (object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e) =>
                        {
                            editor.PutBoolean("skipAppListMessage", e.IsChecked);
                            editor.Apply();
                        };

                         new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogAlert)
                        .SetTitle(string.Format("Add App to the List"))
                        .SetMessage(string.Format("ApP needs to be added to the list to funtion properly.\n"))
                        .SetView(dontShowAgain)
                        .SetPositiveButton("Go to Settings", (o, d) =>
                             {

                                 context.StartActivity(intent);
                                 editor.PutBoolean("skipAppListMessage", true);
                                 editor.Apply();


                             })
                        .SetNegativeButton(Android.Resource.String.Cancel, (o, d) => { })
                        .Show();

                        break;
                   }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [GifImageView-Xamarin.Android](http://githubhttps://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GifImageView-Xamarin.Android) library, it gives you possibility of creating views with gifs, I believe you can then just put it AlertDialog.SetView(**here**). If it doesn't work for you, you can try to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library which also supports gifs,  [there's a Xamarin version here](https://github.com/beraybentesen/glide-xamarin-android)